# ActionbarSherlock : how to remove default text and layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I am developing **Android 2.1 API 7** project. In order to implement action bar, I use the [ActionbarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library.

I have successfully used the **sherlock** library in my project, the problem is that there is always the **default text** showing on the sherlock action bar which is my **project name**.

Even I have used menu layout file (`res/menu/action_menu.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/test"
          android:title="@string/my_test"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

I also inflate above layout in my **Activity** `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu)` method:

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity{

  ...
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

But on the sherlock action bar, the (by default) project name and a android icon are still showing, and it shows on the left side of my custom menu layout item.

So, how to remove the sherlock library default layout and text(project name)??

Answer (score 3):

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
```

The API is exactly that of the [native ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) for future reference.

Comment: @ Jake, Yes, now the default icon and text is gone, but my custom layout item is alway showing on the right most side of the action bar, why?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding two lines, replacing the default logo by change the "**icon.png**" "**header_logo.png**" in drawable